# How do I use a wildcard certificate with SSRS?

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am trying to setup SSRS access via SSL, and I have followed the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345223(v=sql.110).aspx); however, I do not receive a clickable url in the Configuration Manager to click on and test.  The url shows as `https://+:9443/ReportServer`. Based upon [this walkthrough](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configurationmgr/archive/2014/07/23/a-step-by-step-example-of-configuring-a-reporting-services-point-for-https-in-system-center-2012-configuration-manager.aspx) it looks like the url is being provided from the certificate. How can I make this work with the wildcard cert where it can be accessed via `https://sub.domain.com:9443/ReportServer`?

I appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks

Comment: I'd venture a guess that you'll need to push it through the setup process with the wrong name, then manually adjust the name afterward - probably in the registry.  [This image](http://blogs.technet.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-69-06-metablogapi/clip_5F00_image084_5F00_7C9B55FC.gif) has a "URL from registry" line, see if you can track down where that's coming from?

Comment: thanks @ShaneMadden you led me down a path that led to the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following taken from michael12345's answer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c4adad99-ae23-49b0-8487-09ed04501760/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-2008-with-wildcard-ssl-certificate) solved my problem.

1. Shut down the instance.
2. Delete the reservations with:
   `netsh http delete urlacl url=yoururl`
3. Create new ones with:
   `netsh http add urlacl url=yourdomain:yourport/ReportServer user=MYSERVER\MyAccount`
4. Then I edited the rsreportserver.config `URLReservations` section to reflect the URL reservations I added above.  I'm not sure if this necessary, however I felt I should update it so that consistent URLs are shown throughout the configuration tool and logfiles.
5. Start the instance again.

Comment: I thoroughly approve of this answer. ;-)

Comment: @Michael12345 I guess you discovered that the problem wasn't fixed in 2012 :-)